# How to get source line numbers with crash utility in kernel crash debugging

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

I am using this [tutorial](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/oops-debugging-kernel-panics-0) to analyze the dump file generated on kernel crash.

The dump file is successfully generated and I am able to access it using crash utility.

```c
  /* Code for the kernel module */
  #include<linux/module.h>
  #include<linux/kernel.h>
  #include<linux/types.h>
   
  static s32 __init testmoduleinit(void)
  {
          s8 *ptr = NULL;
          pr_info("%s:module loaded.\n", __func__);
          *ptr = 100;     // generate oops
          return 0;
  }
  static void __exit testmoduledeinit(void)
  {
          pr_info("%s:module un-loaded.\n", __func__);
  }
  module_init(testmoduleinit);
  module_exit(testmoduledeinit);
  MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The crash logs(backtrace output) are as follows.

```
crash> bt
PID: 3401   TASK: ffff9d6928b3af00  CPU: 2   COMMAND: "insmod"
 #0 [ffffb2bd846478c8] machine_kexec at ffffffff9246fe83
 #1 [ffffb2bd84647928] __crash_kexec at ffffffff9255a152
 #2 [ffffb2bd846479f8] crash_kexec at ffffffff9255aff1
 #3 [ffffb2bd84647a18] oops_end at ffffffff9243633d
 #4 [ffffb2bd84647a40] no_context at ffffffff924803c9
 #5 [ffffb2bd84647ab0] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff924807c0
 #6 [ffffb2bd84647af8] bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff92480976
 #7 [ffffb2bd84647b08] __do_page_fault at ffffffff9248133d
 #8 [ffffb2bd84647b70] do_page_fault at ffffffff9248162c
 #9 [ffffb2bd84647ba0] page_fault at ffffffff93001284
    [exception RIP: _MODULE_INIT_START_gencrash+44]
    RIP: ffffffffc062b02c  RSP: ffffb2bd84647c58  RFLAGS: 00010282
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: 0000000000000000  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: ffff9d6935c9c8c8  RDI: ffff9d6935c9c8c8
    RBP: ffffb2bd84647c60   R8: 0000000000000722   R9: 0000000000000004
    R10: ffff9d693219f730  R11: 0000000000000001  R12: ffffffffc062b000
    R13: ffff9d693219f730  R14: ffffb2bd84647e68  R15: ffffffffc0628000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#10 [ffffb2bd84647c68] do_one_initcall at ffffffff9240389a
#11 [ffffb2bd84647ce0] do_init_module at ffffffff92edd493
#12 [ffffb2bd84647d08] load_module at ffffffff92556e1b
#13 [ffffb2bd84647e48] __do_sys_finit_module at ffffffff9255773c
#14 [ffffb2bd84647f20] __x64_sys_finit_module at ffffffff9255777a
#15 [ffffb2bd84647f30] do_syscall_64 at ffffffff92405207
#16 [ffffb2bd84647f50] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe at ffffffff9300008c
    RIP: 00007f7f2613c539  RSP: 00007fff5ba4f6a8  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: ffffffffffffffda  RBX: 000056442b32d7c0  RCX: 00007f7f2613c539
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 0000564429214d2e  RDI: 0000000000000003
    RBP: 0000564429214d2e   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 00007f7f2640f000
    R10: 0000000000000003  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: 0000000000000000
    R13: 000056442b32d760  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

The "bt" logs show that page fault is generated at address ffffffffc062b02c.

But when I do

```sh
crash> mod -s test_module ./test_module.o
crash> sym ffffffffc062b02c
```

I don't see the line number in source code which is generating crash.

Is there any way to get the line number from the kernel module which is causing the oops condition.

Comment: The output `exception RIP: _MODULE_INIT_START_gencrash+44` suggests that the crash occured in function `_MODULE_INIT_START_gencrash` which doesn't belong to the module you show us. "I don't see the line number in source code which is generating crash." - What do you **actually** see in the output of `sym ffffffffc062b02c` command?

Comment: ffffffffc062b02c (m) _MODULE_INIT_START_gencrash+44 [gencrash]

//gencrash is the name of kernel module

Comment: No, do not reply with a comment with that output. Instead, add the output to the **question post**. This is how Stack Overflow works: a *comment* **requests** the information, but information should be added to the *question post* itself.

Comment: "gencrash is the name of kernel module" - Then you need to use this name when add the object file for the module: `mod -s gencrash ./test_module.o`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I used the name of kernel module[gencrash] to add the object file in mod -s command, but still i don't see any source line numbers in "sym ffffffffc062b02c " command.